# SVG not working in Firefox 18

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, d3.js

SVG is not working in Firefox 18, but it would be more accurate to say via [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug_%28software%29). I can see the values of the SVG elements changing - but nothing appears on the screen.

The snippet I'm working with is http://jsfiddle.net/jcutrell/3C9JW/5/.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title> - jsFiddle demo by jcutrell</title>

        <script type="text/javascript"
                src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
        </script>
        <style type="text/css"></style>

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                background-color: #555;
                height: 5000px;
            }
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
            $(function(){
                var svg = d3.select("#main");
                var line = d3.svg.line()
                .x(function(d) { return d[0]; })
                .y(function(d) { return d[1] + 200; })
                .interpolate("monotone");

                function init(){
                    var randData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                        randData.push([i*50, Math.random() * 100]);
                    }
                    svg.data([randData])
                       .append("svg:path")
                       .attr("d", line)
                       .attr("fill", "#444")
                       .attr("stroke", "#aaa")
                       .attr("stroke-width", 7);
                    svg.selectAll("circle")
                       .data(randData)
                       .enter().append("circle")
                       .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return d[0]; })
                       .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return d[1] + 200 })
                       .attr("fill", "#dfdfdf")
                       .attr("r", 10);
                    setInterval(refresh, 1200);
                }

                function refresh(){
                    var randData = [];
                    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++){
                        randData.push([i*50, Math.random() * 100]);
                    }

                    svg.data([randData])
                        .select("path")
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr("d", line);
                    svg.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(randData)
                        .transition()
                        .duration(500)
                        .attr("cy", function(d,i){ return d[1] + 200 });
                }
                init();
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v2.js"></script>
        <svg id="main"></svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

It works perfectly fine in Chrome though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set a height and width of the svg element, then it will show up.

Comment: I also needed to add `'px'` to the integers when setting the height and width attributes

Answer (score 1):

To [see things](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/pwsxK/), you need the `width` and `height` attributes on the SVG element. And `width` and `height` CSS properties on the `html` and `body` tags:

```
<svg id="main" width="100%" height="100%"></svg>

html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #555;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple add to the CSS:

```
#main{
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

Or add to the HTML:

```
style width=500px, height=300px
```